# How to add elements to a sub-table within a table, based off a variable length array, when the table is not yet in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I add elements from an array to a sub-table? I have the following code and a table that already exists in the DOM.

```
    var opstasks_len = opstasks.length;


    var table_row = [
       '<tr>',
          '<td>'+date+'</td>',
          '<td>'+rigday+'</td>',
          '<td>'+sport+'</td>',
          '<td>'+week+'</td>',
          '<td>'+teams+'</td>',
          '<td>'+kickoff+'</td>',
          '<td>'+location+'</td>',
          '<td>'+broadcaster+'</td>',
          '<td>'+truck+'</td>',
          '<td>'+product+'</td>',
          '<td>'+tech+'</td>',
          '<td>'+camassist+'</td>',
          '<td>',
            '<table class="roster-opstasks">',
            '</table>',
          '</td>',
        '</tr>'
    ].join('\n');

    _$upcoming_shifts.append(table_row);

    for(var i = 0; i < opstasks_len; i++){    
      if(opstasks[i].length > 0){ 
        $(".roster-opstasks).last().append('<tr><td class="opstasks-entry">'+opstasks[i]+'</tr></td>');
      }
    }

}
```

however this is providing intermittent results i.e. the opstasks table is not being loaded properly but only sometimes like on the 4th or 5th refresh. This is the same across browsers. I suspect because the DOM is often not ready in time and the script is then terminating upon not being able to find the tags.

I have tried creating a series of sub-arrays and joining them together with spread syntax e.g.

```
    var tasks = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < opstasks_len; i++){    
      if(opstasks[i].length > 0){ 
        tasks.push('<tr><td class="opstasks-entry">'+opstasks[i]+'</tr></td>');
      }
    }

    var outer_table_row = [
       '<tr>',
          '<td>'+date+'</td>',
          '<td>'+rigday+'</td>',
          '<td>'+sport+'</td>',
          '<td>'+week+'</td>',
          '<td>'+teams+'</td>',
          '<td>'+kickoff+'</td>',
          '<td>'+location+'</td>',
          '<td>'+broadcaster+'</td>',
          '<td>'+truck+'</td>',
          '<td>'+product+'</td>',
          '<td>'+tech+'</td>',
          '<td>'+camassist+'</td>',
          '<td>',
            '<table class="roster-opstasks">'
    ]

    var inner_outer_table_end = [
          '</table>',
        '</td>',
      '</tr>'
    ];

    var final_table = [...outer_table_start, ...tasks, ...inner_outer_table_end];
    final_table.join('\n');

    _$upcoming_shifts.append(final_table);
```

However that solution meant each new row of that sub table was added after each OUTER table row, which left the 'opstasks' array members appearing to be joined in the 'date' column.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final solution (_$upcoming_shifts is a jquery object that was generated by selecting a table that already exists in the DOM):

```
var add_upcoming_shifts = function(date, rigday, sport, week, teams, kickoff, location, broadcaster, truck, product, tech, camassist, opstasks)
{
    var opstasks_len = opstasks.length;
    var tasks = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < opstasks_len; i++){    
      if(opstasks[i].length > 0){ 
        tasks.push('<tr><td class="opstasks-entry">'+opstasks[i]+'</tr></td>');
      }
    }

    var table_row = [
       '<tr>',
          '<td>'+date+'</td>',
          '<td>'+rigday+'</td>',
          '<td>'+sport+'</td>',
          '<td>'+week+'</td>',
          '<td>'+teams+'</td>',
          '<td>'+kickoff+'</td>',
          '<td>'+location+'</td>',
          '<td>'+broadcaster+'</td>',
          '<td>'+truck+'</td>',
          '<td>'+product+'</td>',
          '<td>'+tech+'</td>',
          '<td>'+camassist+'</td>',
          '<td>',
            '<table class="roster-opstasks">',
              ...tasks,
            '</table>',
          '</td>',
        '</tr>'
    ].join('\n');

    _$upcoming_shifts.append(table_row);
}
```

Comment: You should look into [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), which can be as fast as joining arrays of strings and faster than string concatenation. Also, consider using a [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) and DOM methods to construct your tables; you might find they are even faster than string construction (depending on a number of factors).

Comment: @Heretic Monkey wow DocumentFragment looks wicked! Definitely going to refactor.